# Not able to run dag for python script using Bash Operator

Tags: python, airflow

i have written 2 tasks t1 and t2. which is executing python scripts which are in the given paths.
but the dag execution showing me status as success but the python code didn't run.
i am attaching the code for reference please help me how to run these python scripts.

````
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),datetime.min.time())
todays = datetime.today()

default_args = {
            'owner': 'airflow',
                'depends_on_past': False,
                    'start_date': todays,
                        'email': ['chandresh9410@gmail.com'],
                            'email_on_failure': True,
                                'email_on_retry': False,
                                    'retries': 1,
                                        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
                                            }


my_first_dag = DAG(
            'adag',
                default_args=default_args,
                    description='Our first DAG',
                        schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
                        )

t1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='tocloud',
                bash_command= 'python3 /home/paras/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/scripts/expert_chat_data/parallelOrchestrator.py',
                    dag=my_first_dag)
t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='tobigquery',
            bash_command= 'python3 /home/paras/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/scripts/expert_chat_data/BigQueryIngestion.py',
                dag = my_first_dag)
t1.set_downstream(t2)```
````

Comment: Please add the log of the tasks.

Comment: No logs are comming , it's blank and every time it's showing running status.

Comment: is your scheduler running?

Comment: yes Elad , it's running and i resolved the issue. thank you for your support, i am new to stackoverflow but it's good to see supportive people like you